# MySQL Python connector does not commit

Tags: python, mysql

I have this function that it's supposed  should receive json and store the values on a RDS MySQL db.

```
def saveMetric(metrics):
    cnx     = RDS_Connect()
    cursor  = cnx.cursor()
    jsonMetrics = json.loads(metrics)
    #print type(jsonMetrics['Metrics'])
    # Every 2000 registries, the script will start overriding values
    persistance = 2000
    save_metrics_query = (
            "REPLACE INTO metrics "
            "SET metric_seq = (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(row_id), 0) %% %(persistance)d + 1 FROM metrics AS m), "
            "instance_id = \'%(instance_id)s\', "
            "service = \'%(service)s\' , "
            "metric_name = \'%(metric_name)s\', "
            "metric_value = %(metric_value)f"
           )
    for metric in jsonMetrics['Metrics']:
        formatData = {}
        formatData['persistance'] = persistance
        formatData['instance_id'] = arguments.dimensionValue
        formatData['service'] = jsonMetrics['Service']
        formatData['metric_name'] = metric
        formatData['metric_value'] = jsonMetrics['Metrics'][metric]

        print save_metrics_query % formatData

        try:
            cursor.execute(save_metrics_query, formatData, multi=True)
            logger('info','Metrics were saved successfully!')
            cnx.commit()
        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            logger('error', "Something went wrong: %s" % err)
    cursor.close()
    cnx.close()
```

RDS_Connect() was already tested and it works just fine. The problem is that after running the function, the data is not saved to the DB. I think there is a problem with the commit but I don't see any errors or warning message. If I run the query manually, the data gets stored.

Here is the query that runs after parsing the json:

```
REPLACE INTO metrics SET metric_seq = (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(row_id), 0) % 2000 + 1 FROM metrics AS m), instance_id = 'i-03932937bd67622c4', service = 'AWS/EC2' , metric_name = 'CPUUtilization', metric_value = 0.670000
```

If it helps, this is the json that the function receives:

```
{
"Metrics": {
    "CPUUtilization": 1.33, 
    "NetworkIn": 46428.0, 
    "NetworkOut": 38772.0
}, 
"Id": "i-03932937bd67622c4", 
"Service": "AWS/EC2"
}
```

I'd appreciate some help.

Regards!

UPDATE:

I found that the problem was related to the formatting codes on the query template. 
I re wrote the function like this:

```
def saveMetric(metrics):
    cnx     = RDS_Connect()
    jsonMetrics = json.loads(metrics)
    print json.dumps(jsonMetrics,indent=4)

    persistance = 2000
    row_id_query_template = "SELECT COALESCE(MAX(row_id), 0) % {} + 1 FROM metrics AS m"
    row_id_query = row_id_query_template.format(persistance)

    save_metrics_query = (
        "REPLACE INTO metrics "
        "SET metric_seq = (" + row_id_query + "),"
        "instance_id = %(instance_id)s,"
        "service = %(service)s,"
        "metric_name = %(metric_name)s,"
        "metric_value = %(metric_value)s"
       )

    for metric in jsonMetrics['Metrics']:
        formatData = {}
        formatData['instance_id'] = arguments.dimensionValue
        formatData['service'] = jsonMetrics['Service']
        formatData['metric_name'] = metric
        formatData['metric_value'] = jsonMetrics['Metrics'][metric]

        if arguments.verbose == True:
            print "Data: ",formatData
            print "Query Template: ",save_metrics_query.format(**formatData)

        try:
            cursor  = cnx.cursor()
            cursor.execute(save_metrics_query, formatData)
            logger('info','Metrics were saved successfully!')
            cnx.commit()
            cursor.close()
        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            logger('error', "Something went wrong: %s" % err)

    cnx.close()
```

As you can see, I format the SELECT outside. I believe the whole problem was due to this line:

```
"metric_value = %(metric_value)f"
```

I changed to:

```
"metric_value = %(metric_value)s"
```

and now it works. I think the formatting was wrong, given a syntax error (tho I don't know how the exception was never thrown).

Thanks to everyone who took time to help me!

Comment: The title of your question refers to a failure to commit to the database, but your code and the text of the question refers to the JSON your function is processing.  Does code that directly writes to the database also fail?  Can you provide the minimum code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: can you please show the import of `RDS_Connect()`

Comment: also can you please print out `jsonMetrics['Metrics']` since your commit is inside of a for loop that depends on that not being empty

Comment: Where is the object `arguments` created?  It seems to spawn out of nowhere.

Comment: ...and the `metric_value` in your query that runs after the parsing doesn't match up to the JSON you're giving us.  ...not necessarily a problem, but when a bunch of things don't add up, your question becomes more suspect.  Are you showing us what is really happening?

Comment: brycem The question is about the commit, as the title expresses. I only pasted the json to show people how the input looked like. So this is the code that writes to the database. As you can see, there is an cursor.execute sentence there.

Comment: This is just a function. Not the whole code. The argument processing is working just fine. No need to look at that. It's tested code.

Comment: Also, the content of jsonMetrics[Metrics] is the "Metrics" you see in the json i pasted on the question.

Comment: And last. The loop is not going over empty stuff. As a proof of that, the query i just pasted there is the output of this that print inside the loop. I'm not close to a computer now. I'm on my cellphone

Comment: @Gerrat, that json is not static. I get the information from a call to CloudWatch using boto3. That's some random json I printed. An example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution. I changed:

```
"metric_value = %(metric_value)f"
```

To:

```
"metric_value = %(metric_value)s"
```

Doing some troubleshooting I found a syntax error on the SQL. Somehow the exception didn't show.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't actually used MySQL, but the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) seem to indicate that calling `cursor.execute` with multi=True just returns an iterator.  If that is true, then it wouldn't actually insert anything - you'd need to call `.next()` on the iterator (or just iterate over it) to actually insert the record.

It also goes on to advise against using parameters with `multi=True`:

> If multi is set to True, execute() is able to execute multiple statements specified in the operation string. It returns an iterator that enables processing the result of each statement. However, using parameters does not work well in this case, and it is usually a good idea to execute each statement on its own.

tl;dr: remove that parameter, as the default is False.